# Get data from mysql table and use them in "IN" in sql query (PHP)

Tags: php

I have this php script to get data from database:

```
$sev = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT(SRV) FROM customers WHERE custValue NOT REGEXP '^$' AND id=345532 AND custValue IN ("A+", "B", "C") ");
```

When I try the sql query on database server, it correctly returns following data:

```
________
|  SRV  |
---------
|   A+  |
|   B   |
|   C   |
|   XN  |
|   BN  |
|   DS  |
|   XA  |
---------
```

then I try to implode..

```
$custSev = mysqli_fetch_array($sev);
$csImp = "'" . implode("','", $custSev) . "'";
```

and as the last step I use $csImp in another query

```
... AND severity IN ($csImp) AND ...
```

but when I check it on database server, it receives following sql query:

```
... AND severity IN ('A+','A+') AND ...
```

I have no idea why there is the first value twice and no other value. It should be

```
... AND severity IN ('A+','A+','C','XN','BN','DS','XA') AND ...
```

And again, when I execute this query on DB server, it's working correctly. I'm struggling with this for whole day and tried many combinations without effect. I'm still beginner in PHP. Thank you

I've tried to change $sev to $sev = array('A+','A+','C','XN','BN','DS','XA'); but then in the sql query is "...IN ('')..."

I've tried the following:

```
$row = $sev -> fetch_assoc();
$show = printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["SRV"]);
```

and implode the $show variable and use it in the query, but the "...severity IN ('')..." was empty like in previous case.

Comment: Why? If you have the data in SQL then you can use it as a subquery

Comment: Hi Dharman. It sounds logical, but there are several other conditions in PHP script and sometimes this query should not be executed.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` just returns one row. You're only putting the values from the first row in `$csImp`

Comment: Then you should use prepared statements and probably some query builder. You should always use prepared statements and always bind parameters.

Comment: @Dharman mysqli doesn't make it easy to use prepared statements with variable numbers of parameters.

Comment: @Barmar True, but that is OP's problem. PDO would be easier to use but still it wouldn't make it completely easy to bind a variable number of parameters. It doesn't mean that it should not be done.

Comment: `custValue NOT REGEXP '^$'` can be simplified to `custValue != ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you have retrieved here is in several rows:

```
________
|  SRV  |
---------
|   A+  |
|   B   |
|   C   |
|   XN  |
|   BN  |
|   DS  |
|   XA  |
---------
```

But this code only retrieves the first row:

```
$custSev = mysqli_fetch_array($sev);
$csImp = "'" . implode("','", $custSev) . "'";
```

Unless you specify otherwise, you'll retrieve an array index by column name **and** by a numeric index, hence two entries, which when imploded gives:

```
... AND severity IN ('A+','A+') AND ...
```

As has been pointed out in the comments, you could just use a subquery to do this, but to answer the problem you've posted:

```
$severityList = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sev)) {
    $severityList[] = $row['SRV'];

}
$csImp = "'" . implode("','", $severityList) . "'";
```

**Disclaimer - I haven't tested this. Apologies for any typos!

Comment: Thank you, Tangentially Perpendicular, thanks to you I will spend this night in bed ;) Really, thank you very much, it's working perfectly! ..and sorry for so basic question.